# offchain-workers vs asynchronous task

Tags: runtime, offchain-worker, service

There is not much info about using an asynchronous task in substrate docs i.e. `task_manager` in `service.rs`

I want to know when one should be using `offchain-worker` and when one should use background asynchronous tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding, tasks are some client-only properties.

OCW has the ability to access the runtime directly. It's much easier to query the storage and submit some off-chain extrinsics.

Examples:

If you want to watch your disk usage periodically, use the service task.

If you want to submit the `I'm online` messages periodically, use the OCW.